# Cucumber: can't convert nil to string TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, cucumber, null, typeerror

filter_movie_list.feature

`When I check the following ratings: PG, R`

movie_steps.rb

```
When /^I check the following ratings: (.*)/ do |rating_list|
  within(:id => 'ratings_form') do
    rating_list.split(', ').each do |rating|
      check("ratings_#{rating}")
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.haml

```
= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get, :id => 'ratings_form' do
  = hidden_field_tag "title_sort", true if @title_header
  = hidden_field_tag ":release_date_sort", true if @date_header
  Include: 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, @selected_ratings.include?(rating), :id => "ratings_#{rating}"
  = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => 'ratings_submit'
```

I get this error:

```
When I check the following ratings: PG, R          #step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:21
  can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
  (eval):2:in `find'
  ./step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:22:in `/^I check the following ratings: (.*)/'
  filter_movie_list.feature:26:in `When I check the following ratings: PG, R'
```

What do?

EDIT: Sorry for the n00bishness (formatting errors)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3954397

Comment: Where is "line 22" in `movie_steps.rb`?

Comment: that is the within(:id => 'ratings_form') do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `within` to read:  `within('#ratings_form')` and see if that changes anything...

Comment: yay :D  As far as I know `within()` accepts only css selectors.  Haven't seen any documentation supporting that `:id =>` options hash you were sending.  Glad it was a simple fix :)